# Webpack vue error

Tags: webpack, babeljs, vue.js

I have webpack installed globally and have vue and loaders installed locally and have tried installing them globally. I keep getting this error when I run webpack

```
Module parse failed: /Users/joebob/Development/vue-test/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js!/Users/joebob/Development/vue-test/src/main.js Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import Vue from 'vue';
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './app.vue'

new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    components: { App }
})
```

config

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        path: './dist',
        publicPath: 'dist/',
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue'
            }
        ]
    },
    vue: {
        loaders: {
            js: 'babel'
        }
    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "vue-test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^1.0.16"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.1.2",
        "babel-loader": "^6.1.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.1.2",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.2",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.1.2",
        "babel-runtime": "^5.8.0",
        "webpack": "^1.12.2",
        "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
        "vue-loader": "^7.3.0",
        "vue-html-loader": "^1.0.0",
        "vue-hot-reload-api": "^1.2.0"
    }
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing

Comment: Which version of babel are you using? Can you post your package.json?

Comment: Updated with package.json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing es-2015 transformation.

Pre-6.x, Babel enabled certain transformations by default. However, Babel 6.x does not ship with any transformations enabled. You need to explicitly tell it what transformations to run. The simplest way to do this is by using a preset, such as the ES2015 Preset. You can install it with

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

And then setup **babel-loader** to use it:

config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',      
    output: {              
        path: './dist',
        publicPath: 'dist/',
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
    module: { 
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
                query: {
                  presets: ['es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue'
            }
        ]
    },
    vue: {
        loaders: {
            js: 'babel'
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:

https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#webpack

Comment: Ah yes the preset, I was missing my .babelrc -_- thanks.